# Using ORM's with external, read only systems

Tags: orm

How do ORM's work when accessing read only, external systems?
Say for example I was creating an ordering system that had it's own database that would be accessed through the ORM layers of my application. Part of this system is checking an external system through SQL calls (No web service available) for things such as products/stock on hand.

Is it possible for this part of the system to use an ORM or what you have to code difference classes yourself that access the data and return objects, such as the objects returned from the ORM would? I guess doing it this way, the higher layers would not need to know that products/stock on hand are coming from a separate system.

Any input appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the past when I had to deal with setups like yours, I created a view in the local database (SQL Server) that read data from the remote database. Then I generated wrapper data objects (entities in Entity Framework) for the views.

Every time data was needed from the remote data source, a generated ORM object would be used to access the data object for the view so the call passed through the ORM framework as any other local call would do.

The remote data source can be set up as a linked server, through [`OPENDATASOURCE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) or it can be a different database on the same server (this is for SQL Server). There may be other options that I'm not thinking of and other databases may support different setups.

So remote data appeared as local - as far as the ORM framework was concerned, data was coming from a data object that was part of the framework. The real remoting happened in the database view. Because of this, there was no difference on the higher levels of the application between remote and local data. This approach works for Entity Framework / .NET and the one I used some years ago and I'm fairly sure other ORM frameworks would be able to use this approach (on other platforms).

Comment: Thanks for that. So you setup the remote data source as a linked server?

Comment: @Lock Using SQL Server yes. It's also possible that the same server is used but the data is in different databases - in that case you'd simply refer to the remote table using its fully qualified name. The same is true for stored procedures - they can be local to the ORM but go to a remote server / database.